# Stopping Flash/Javascript Loaded Images/Videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, images, browser-addons, flash, javascript

I would like to stop flash and javascript loaded images from automatically loading in FF. How can I accomplish this with the use of add-ons?

Please note disabling javascript by default is not an option as many pages will not work without JS enabled. Also I currently use Flashblock to stop flash but it still allows some flash to leak through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NoScript](http://noscript.net/) helps blocking Flash, Javascript and other "unasked-for" content. Another solution that's not restricted to a single application would consist of using a filtering proxy like [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/). Thus, all other applications that may access content via HTTP (Thunderbird for mails in HTML, for example) will benefit from a single set of filtering rules.